# Deleting UITextField content when deleting row from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a table view in my app that has 6 rows, Player One to Player Six. The user enters the players names and can delete rows by swiping and tapping 'Delete' I am running into a problem when there is text in a row's text field. For example I fill in the first 3 rows' text field with 'One' to 'Three'. If you delete row 3 that says 'Three', it will delete the row but the text 'Three' in the text field will go into the row underneath for Player Four. What is the best way to fix this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"playerCell";
    playerCell *cell = [tableView
                            dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.playerLabel.text = [[_playerNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cell.playerNameBox.text];
    cell.playerNameBox.tag = indexPath.row;

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
     setObject:test forKey:key];

    return cell;
}
```

Deleting a row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [_playerNames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [Table reloadData];

    }
}
```

Number of rows in section = 6

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _playerNames.count;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you have a custom class for your cell, in the `prepareForReuse` method, set the text field to `nil`.

Comment: Doing that deletes the text in every text field. Is there a way to just delete the text in that row's text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`" method, you're not checking properly for an nil object case.

Instead of:

```
cell.playerLabel.text = [[_playerNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Do:

```
NSString *title = [[_playerNames objectAtInex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title];
cell.playerLabel.text = (title ? title : @""); // set the label to either title or the empty string
```

I suspect what's happening is that you're not properly resetting the text label upon reloading or reuse.

But anyways, instead of reloading the data, why not be super cool and *delete* the row that was marked for deletion.

I.E.:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [_playerNames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationLeft]; 
    }
}
```

Another FYI:

I noticed you had:

```
    [Table reloadData];
```

in your code.  Best practices for Objective-C are to ***not*** name your instance variables with capital letters.  It should be something more descriptive, like "`itemTable`".

Comment: That worked. I've never used table views before so am still learning how they work. In the process of renaming my instance variables.